# ¿Cuál es el limite de solicitudes http a un archivo en un repositorio de git hub?

Tags: flutter, github, http

Cree una aplicación en flutter donde tengo un método que realiza una solicitud http a un archivo que tengo almacenado en un repositorio de tipo publico de mi gitHub, y quiero saber cual es el limite de solicitudes que se pueden realizar al mismo tiempo o al día.

La razón de la pregunta es que estoy implementando un método para verificar si la app esta actualizada o no, busque información sobre esto pero no encontré, asique lo que se me ocurrió fue hacer esto, pero me surgió la pregunta de cual seria el limite de solicitudes que se podrían realizar al día o al mismo tiempo.

Codigo:

```
    final response = await http.get( Uri.parse('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return response.body;
    } else {
      return '!404!';
    }
  }
```

Busque información sobre esto y lo que encontré fue cito textualmente ¨Para las solicitudes no autenticadas, el límite de tasa permite hasta 60 solicitudes por hora. Las solicitudes sin autenticar se asocian con la dirección IP original y no con la persona que las realiza.¨
Enlace:https://docs.github.com/es/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28

Pero también se menciona que cito textualmente ¨Usuario a servidor se limitan a 5000 por hora y por usuario autenticado. Todas las solicitudes de las aplicaciones de OAuth autorizadas por un usuario o un personal access token propiedad del usuario, y las solicitudes autenticadas con cualquiera de las credenciales de autenticación del usuario, comparten la misma cuota de 5000 solicitudes por hora para ese usuario.

Las solicitudes de usuario a servidor están sujetas a un límite alto de 15,000 solicitudes por hora y por usuario autenticado en los siguientes escenarios.

La solicitud es desde una GitHub App que pertenece a una organización de GitHub Enterprise Cloud.
La solicitud es desde una OAuth App que pertenece a o está aprobada por una organización de GitHub Enterprise Cloud.¨
Enlace:https://docs.github.com/es/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28

En conclusión quisiera saber si esta forma de hacerlo es la mas optima o debería de buscar alguna otra opción? y si es así que me recomiendan.

Comment: Te has respondido tu mismo: *"Para las solicitudes no autenticadas, el límite de tasa permite hasta 60 solicitudes por hora"*. Si quieres un mejor servicio, lo normal sería utilizar un servidor propio puesto que cualquier opción gratuita va a tener límites sea de llamadas, sea de velocidad, sea de capacidad... Un VPS baratillo por un par de euros al mes sirve para muchas cosas, incluido jugar a desplegar tus propios backend para cualquier aplicación que hagas, y los límites suelen ser muchísimo mejores, con uso de red ilimitado y muy buena velocidad.

Comment: Conoces algún servicio que me recomiendes ?, y gracias por confirmar.